# Sklearn Univariate Selection Type Error

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am having a type error with the below code, where Factor A and B is used to predict C

```
df = df[['A','B','C']]
print (df.head())
print (df.tail())


from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

names = ['A','B']
for n in range(0, len(names)):
    test = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=all)
    fit = test.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print(" %s : %.2f") % (names[n], fit.scores_[n])
```

The dataframe is as per below

```
           A         B              C
1  -0.000078  0.115441              0
2  -0.002767  0.089734              1
3  -0.000848  0.069986              1
4   0.001235  0.079025              1
5   0.004776  0.087153              0
              A        B               C
2831  -0.001210  0.109015              1
2832  -0.003597  0.109474              1
2833   0.000190  0.115139              1
2834   0.003153  0.134228              1
2835   0.005453  0.133333              0
```

It produces the following error

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

I dont understand how to solve this error, can anyone advise please?

Answer (score 0):

In

```
SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=all)
```

`all` is a built-in Python function. What you need is

```
SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k="all")
```

to have a *string*.

Also, X values are required to be non-negative for this method, so if you are using `df[['A', 'B']]` as `X_train` that is going to be a problem too.

Finally, putting the fit method in that loop makes no sense. You probably wanted the loop for printing.

Here is an example that works; I took `abs` of X values to make them non-negative; whether or not this makes sense in your context I cannot tell.

```
test = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k="all")
fit = test.fit(np.abs(df[['A', 'B']]), df['C'])
for n in range(len(names)):
  print("{} : {:.2g}".format(names[n], fit.scores_[n]))
```